# Laravel Model Relationships - What kind of relationship am I trying to create?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have got 3 models associated with this question; Country, Manufacturer and Region.

I've simplified the tables for the sake of this question. I don't think anything else in the tables or any of the other models are anything to do with the problem.

My tables are set up like so;

```
manufacturers
 - id
 - name

countries
 - id
 - name

regions
 - id
 - name
 - manufacturer_id
 - country_id
```

What I want to be able to do is to write `$manufacturer->countries` in my blade and have it spit out the countries that are associated with a given manufacturer.

The models are currently related to each other like this;

Country.php

```
public function manufacturers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Manufacturer::class);
}

public function regions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Region::class);
}
```

Region.php

```
public function manufacturer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Manufacturer::class);
}

public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}
```

and where I'm having the problem, Manufacturer.php

I think I need a hasMany relationship. I've already got;

```
public function regions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Region::class);
}
```

and I would have thought I would have needed;

```
public function countries()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Country::class,Region::class);
}
```

but that leads to this error;

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'countries.region_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `countries`.*, `regions`.`manufacturer_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `countries` inner join `regions` on `regions`.`id` = `countries`.`region_id` where `regions`.`manufacturer_id` = 4)
```

so I tried swapping the classes round to give;

```
public function countries()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Region::class,Country::class);
}
```

but that leads to;

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'countries.manufacturer_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `regions`.*, `countries`.`manufacturer_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `regions` inner join `countries` on `countries`.`id` = `regions`.`country_id` where `countries`.`manufacturer_id` = 4)
```

Does anyone know how I should be setting my relationships up in order to achieve what I want?

I also tried a `belongsToMany` relationship, which did bring back the countries, but multiple instances of the same country. I just want one instance of each country that appears in the regions table for any given manufacturer.

Comment: From what I am getting, correct me if I am wrong, one `manufacturer` can be in multiple `countries`, and one `country` can have multiple `manufacturers` and the `regions` table is just a connector table, no real value. Am I right? Cause if that's the case then you'll need `Many to many` relationship.

Comment: Hi, the regions table does have some value. I've edited my question slightly to reflect that fact that all of the tables have a name field, which is important. A Manufacturer can be part of several countries, each of which is split up into several regions, so currently I have a manufacturer that has 4 regions with in one country, there could be 4 (any number) more in a different country too, and so on...

Comment: Kindly update your answer with all the models with relationships.

Comment: @sumeet There are 8 models, the question would be over 1km long. I really don't think it's necessary or applicable to the question in this instance. I also have users who can have a region_id depending on whether or not they are regional managers and responsible for that region, and appointments, that will have been made in region for a given manufacturer. Dealerships are also in a single region for a given manufacturer. I don't think any of that matters to this particular relationship though.

Comment: @JordanD I mean update current question with belongsToMany relationship. `$manufacturer->countries` will return you collection. Please check collection documentation. `unique` :)

Comment: Thanks, I have done that for now and it does solve the problem so thank you for that. It is my understanding that I can only use this in my blade/contoller files though. What I would like in an ideal world though is to be able to place something on the model relationship that would do this, as it will be getting used like this everytime and would create DRYer code through me not having to write `unique` everytime I returned the collection.

Comment: @JordanD You can add a method in the model which returns unique countries

Comment: great, how? I've looked and I can't find anything that does that... Can you point me in the direction of a link that talks about it please?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually dealing with the many-to-many relationship.

In your case `regions` is a pivot table.

Kindly check belongsToMany.

Answer (score 0):

In `Laravel`, the best relationship to apply is `many to many` relationship. What this means as applied to your case is that 1 `country` can have multiple `manufacturers` and 1 `manufacturer` can be in multiple countries.

If that is the case, you don't need to create a `regions` table, but rather a `pivot table.` The default naming convention in laravel is (singular and om alphabetic order), that is, `country_manufacturer` table and it will contain (You can always add an extra variable known as `pivot` value):

```
country_manufacturer
  - id
  - name // pivot value
  - manufacturer_id
  - country_id
```

Then, in the models, add `belongsToMany` relationship, i.e.

In Manufacturer model (without pivot) :

```
public function countries()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Manufacturer::class);
}
```

In Country Model (With pivot):

```
public function manufacturers()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class)->withPivot('name');
}
```

Hence, you will be able to call  `$country->manufacturers()` which will give you a list of all the manufacturers in the `$country` and the reverse is true: `$manufacturer->countries` will give you all the countries the manufacturer is based in.

Comment: OK, I understand what you are saying I think, and thank you for the repsonse. I've just used regions as the pivot table, it's structured the same as your country_manufacturer table, but when I'm echoing out foreach($manufacturer->countries as $country) it's bringing back 4 instances of the country, because there are 4 regions with in that country for the given manufacturer. I only want it to bring back 1 instance of each country. Do you know how I go about doing that?

Comment: By the way... have you got the classes the wrong way round? i.e. countries() belongsToMany(Country::class). That's what i'm using because that's what seems to work in bringing back (too many instances of) the country.